# composer autoload problem how to solve this?

Tags: laravel

PHP Warning:

> require(/home/praveenkumar/Documents/mahesh/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/praveenkumar/Documents/mahesh/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/praveenkumar/Documents/mahesh/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/praveenkumar/Documents/mahesh/artisan on line 18

Comment: Try `composer install` instead.

Comment: Try `composer install` and then `composer update` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the composer in your project directory.
Use the command `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer install`, this will import your packages and create the vendor folder, along with the autoload script.

`composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer install`

But after running the first command, if your are still facing the problem, then run `composer update`

**N.B:** Make sure you run these commands inside your project directory.

Hopefully this will work for you.